# Dojo Tree based on ItemFileReadStore and parent-based model

Tags: javascript, json, tree, dojo

I'm trying to programmatically create a dojo tree from a json file. The problem is that my json objects reference to their parents not children as in some examples.
Unfortunately my output looks only like this:

[image]

I have the following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
require(["dijit/Tree", "dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore", "dijit/tree/ForestStoreModel", "dijit/tree/ObjectStoreModel", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(Tree, ItemFileReadStore, ObjectStoreModel, ForestStoreModel){
var store = new ItemFileReadStore({
    url: "/_data/test.json",
    getChildren: function(object){
        return this.query({F_TopLevelCategoryID: object.P_CategoryID});
    }
});

var myModel = new ObjectStoreModel({
    store: store,
    labelAttr:'CategoryName',
    query: {"P_CategoryID": 0}
});

var myTree = new Tree({
    model: myModel
}, "treeOne");
myTree.startup();
});
</script>
```

The json file looks like the following:

```
{ "identifier" : "P_CategoryID",
  "label" : "CategoryName",
"items" : [ { "CategoryName" : "Category 1",
    "F_TopLevelCategoryID" : 0,
    "P_CategoryID" : 1
  },
  { "CategoryName" : "Category 2",
    "F_TopLevelCategoryID" : 1,
    "P_CategoryID" : 2
  },
  { "CategoryName" : "Category 3",
    "F_TopLevelCategoryID" : 1,
    "P_CategoryID" : 3
  },
  { "CategoryName" : "Category 4",
    "F_TopLevelCategoryID" : 1,
    "P_CategoryID" : 4
  },
  { "CategoryName" : "Category 5",
    "F_TopLevelCategoryID" : 3,
    "P_CategoryID" : 5
  },
  { "CategoryName" : "Category 6",
    "F_TopLevelCategoryID" : 4,
    "P_CategoryID" : 6
  },
  { "CategoryName" : "Category 7",
    "F_TopLevelCategoryID" : 4,
    "P_CategoryID" : 7
  },
  { "CategoryName" : "Category 8",
    "F_TopLevelCategoryID" : 0,
    "P_CategoryID" : 8
  },
  { "CategoryName" : "Top Level Category",
    "P_CategoryID" : 0
  }
]
}
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it was a fluke that you received a partial result.

You have forestStoreModel and objectStoreModel transposed in the require block, and referencing parents is fine!

Also, use dojo/store instead of ItemFileReadStore, as the latter is deprecated. Use the data parameter on Memory:

```
var store = new Memory({
  data: testJson,
  getChildren: ...
});
```

See my working fiddle here, using dojo/store/Memory: https://jsfiddle.net/yubp45sa/

You can get your data into the memory store using dojo/request:

```
request("testData.json").then(...);
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/request.html

I had another request example in previously, which requested the data through a GET from a custom nodeJS route (returning JSON):

```
request.get("/configInfo", {
  handleAs: "json"
}).then(...);
```

Comment: this works like a charm, thanks a lot! 
I already had a working snippet with the memory store in place and could add the request function to retrieve the data from an URL. :)